# Checking a string with ::isdigit not working with string that holds a decimal

Tags: c++, string, numbers

Hopefully there is a quick answer/solution to this problem that I am just not seeing. Ok so what I am trying to do is I have a string which is holding a price for an item. I then need to take that string value and convert it to a number. I must use a string to have the price as I am getting the price from a text file. I know the decimal in the price is what is causing the issue as when I changed the price from 7.99 by removing the decimal this worked and the price was stored. I have the code segment I am refering to pasted bellow.

```
if( all_of(price.begin(), price.end(), ::isdigit))
{
    anItem->setPrice(atof(price.c_str())) ;  
}
```

Am I just making a silly mistake? Is there a way to correct this so I can convert the string to a number (I am storing the price as a float)?

Thank you for your help!!! :)

Comment: You can use `std::stof` for an exception or something like `std::strtof` for a more C-like approach. `atof` is terrible because it has no error checking besides a valid output. Either of those and no need to check the string yourself.

Comment: It is working now as I wanted it to work! I should really get around to looking at the new standards as it might make my life easier! Thanks a lot!!!